# I want to convert a char (popped from the stack) to integer

Tags: c, arrays, char

```
char i[]=pop();
char j[]=pop();
b=atoi(i);
a=atoi(j);
```

I wanted to pop an `char` type element from stack and convert it to int type. But it says

> invalid initializer.

What is the problem?

Comment: What does `pop()` return?

Comment: Umm.. stack? what stack?  pop?  what pop?   The only thing that makes less sense is that three answerers think that it makes sense:(

Comment: @MartinJames It actually makes sense (thought I agree it's not a great question, anyway). :) The problem seems to be with the array notation, which is wrong and not needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a `char` variable, use a `char` variable, don't use a `char` array.

Change

```
char i[] = pop();
```

to

```
char i = pop();
```

and likewise.

That said, `atoi()` won't be relevant there. If you want the result to be of type `int`, simply use an `int` variable.